# cumulative profit of each client in table no 2 from data of table 1

Tags: microsoft-excel, database

[image]

I want cumulative profit of each client in table no 2 from data of table 1 
formula i use is ""IF(B19=B3,D3,0)+IF(B19=B4,D4,0)+IF(B19=B5,D5,0)+IF(B19=B6,D6,0)+IF(B19=B7,D7,0)+IF(B19=B8,D8,0)+IF(B19=B9,D9,0)+IF(B19=B10,D10,0)+IF(B19=B11,D11,0)+IF(B19=B12,D12,0)+IF(B19=B13,D13,0)""
 which work fine for fewer rows in table one but become tideous for many rows 
Please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what you are looking for is the `SUMIF` function.
Try putting this in `L4`: `=SUMIF($B$4:$B$14,$K4,$D$4:$D$14)` and then drag down to `L8`.